# Django form: set CSS class for list of choices

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I have a modelform in Django with a field `answer` represented by check boxes. I want to be able to identify the list of choices by a CSS class. Currently, I have modified the `__init__` method for the form and set the `class` attribute for the widget.

```
class CheckboxForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CheckboxForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={
                'class': 'checkbox-a',
            }),
        )
    # ...
```

However, this sets the class for each of the individual checkbox inputs, like this:

```
<ul id="id_answer">
    <li><label for="id_answer_0">
        <input class="checkbox-a" type="checkbox">
    </label></li>
    <li><label for="id_answer_1">
        <input class="checkbox-a" type="checkbox">
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

Instead, I want to set the class the `ul` of inputs, like this:

```
<ul id="id_answer" class="checkbox-a">
    <li><label for="id_answer_0">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </label></li>
    <li><label for="id_answer_1">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to do that? I'm open to using jQuery/JavaScript, though having some way to put it in the form/model would be ideal.

**Note:** I can't base it just use the `id_answer` instead of a class because there are actually multiple forms on the page using prefixes and I want this to be able to apply to all of them.

Comment: Are you using `{{ form.as_ul }}` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/) "A widget is Django’s representation of a HTML input element." 
That mean widgets is for inputs tags not for others tags like ul or li.

You can select a parent selector from the input tag with jquery

```
 $("ul:has(.checkbox-a)")
```

or

```
 $("input.checkbox-a").closest("ul")
```

Comment: Where are you saying I should put this? PyCharm is informing me that `has` is an invalid selector outside of jQuery, but that's not jQuery code you posted. I believe the jQuery would be something of the form `$("ul").has("li input.checkbox-a")`, but that's not working.

Comment: sry, I was confusing with jquery and the parent method.